# Sitecatalyst : Difference between 2 & 5 level correlation

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

What is the difference between 2 & 5 level correlation. How do I enable correlation in SC so it can be viewed in the actual report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific level correlations no longer exist in the current version of Adobe Analytics. All traffic variables can be correlated an unlimited number of times.

Back when 2 and 5 (and 20) level correlations existed, they allowed you link a number of traffic variables so you could see what other variables were defined when a different traffic variable was set to a specific value. A 5 level correlation could have 5 different variables, all of which you could view breakdowns of each other.

[View Correlations in the Adobe Analytics documentation](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/reference/correlation.html)

Comment: Hey Gigaelle Thanks  for your Answer, it's really helpful for me.